# Apache2.2 wsgi: can not import python modules

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

the apache2 error log:

```
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1] mod_wsgi (pid=32472): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/pkgs/myprogram/extras/myprogram.wsgi'.
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1]   File "/opt/pkgs/myprogram-deps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1]     response = self.get_response(request)
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1]   File "/opt/pkgs/myprogram-deps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 199, in get_response
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1]   File "/opt/pkgs/myprogram-deps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 239, in handle_uncaught_exception
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1]     if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1]   File "/opt/pkgs/myprogram-deps/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7-py2.7.egg/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 361, in urlconf_module
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1]     __import__(name)
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1]   File "/opt/pkgs/myprogram/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myprogram-2.3.10-py2.7.egg/myprogect/urls.py", line 3, in <module>
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1]     from views import index, login, logout
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1]   File "/opt/pkgs/myprogram/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myprogram-2.3.10-py2.7.egg/myprogram/views.py", line 2, in <module>
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1]     import dashboard.views
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1]   File "/opt/pkgs/myprogram/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myprogram-2.3.10-py2.7.egg/dashboard/views.py", line 5, in <module>
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1]     from lib.pdfgenerator import PDFGenerator
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1]   File "/opt/pkgs/myprogram/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myprogram-2.3.10-py2.7.egg/lib/pdfgenerator.py", line 1, in <module>
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1]     from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
[Fri Dec 18 17:25:14 2015] [error] [client 10.32.64.1] ImportError: No module named reportlab.lib.pagesizes
```

Part of my apache2conf:

```
WSGIPythonEggs /opt/data/myproject/tmp
WSGIPythonHome /usr
WSGIPythonPath /opt/pkgs/myproject-deps/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/opt/pkgs/myproject-portal/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I guess apache2 can not find the right python modules. But I have no idea how to do the settings in apache2.conf. Most important, no idea about how to debug?

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm the reportlab module is available? Try using the Python interpreter and import reportlab.

Comment: I did not find import reportlab. I will install it and try again.

Comment: @PatrickBeeson How to check whether reportlab is in site-packages OR lib/?

Comment: @ChengchengPei After `import reportlab` then `reportlab.__file__` will tell you what directory the module is in.